# Expressions with in Expressions SQL

Tags: sql, expression, field

I'm going to first off apologize for my butchered SQL. Newbie here.

Here is my issue.

```
   SELECT Day,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN
          Shopping.Fruits Like '%1%'
            THEN
              'DewBerry'
        WHEN
          Shopping.Fruits Like '%2%'
            THEN
              'Kiwi'
         WHEN 
            Shopping.Fruits Like '%3%'
             THEN
               'Tangerine'
         ELSE
            'Inactive'
      END) AS Total, ***Total As FruitType***
    FROM Shopping
    GROUP BY Day
    ORDER BY Day desc
```

Everything works except what I surrounded with "***", I'm trying to display the FruitType field. My attempt did not work. I feel like its something small I am overlooking but I can't seem to get it.

This is what I get with out ***Total As FruitType***

```
Day             Total
9/11/2018 0:00  24
9/10/2018 0:00  113
9/9/2018 0:00   17
9/7/2018 0:00   62
9/6/2018 0:00   94
9/5/2018 0:00   15
```

Anything helps,

Thank you....

Comment: What is the "FruitType" field?  What results are you looking for?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was trying to take the created ***Total*** as a second Field to display 3 summed rows (Tangerine, DewBerry, and Kiwi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could look like

```
  SELECT 
    Day,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Shopping.Fruits Like '%1%' THEN 1
             ELSE 0  
         END
       ) AS DewBerry_Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Shopping.Fruits Like '%2%' THEN 1
             ELSE 0  
         END
       ) AS Kiwi_Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Shopping.Fruits Like '%3%' THEN 1
             ELSE 0  
         END
       ) AS Tangerine_Count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Shopping.Fruits NOT LIKE '%1%'
              AND Shopping.Fruits NOT LIKE '%2%'
              AND Shopping.Fruits NOT LIKE '%3%' THEN 1
             ELSE 0  
         END
       ) AS Inactive_Count
    FROM ScreeningManu
    GROUP BY Day
    ORDER BY Day desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
SELECT s.Day,
       (CASE WHEN s.Fruits Like '%1%' THEN 'DewBerry'
             WHEN s.Fruits Like '%2%' THEN 'Kiwi'
             WHEN s.Fruits Like '%3%' THEN 'Tangerine'
            ELSE 'Inactive'
       END) as FruitType,
      COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM ScreeningManu s
GROUP BY s.Day,
         (CASE WHEN s.Fruits Like '%1%' THEN 'DewBerry'
               WHEN s.Fruits Like '%2%' THEN 'Kiwi'
               WHEN s.Fruits Like '%3%' THEN 'Tangerine'
               ELSE 'Inactive'
          END)
ORDER BY s.Day DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistant I messed up and put FROM ScreeningManu and Meant to put FROM Shopping. I have to censor some data. Haha.